# ASP.Net Core 2.2 App fails on unsecured HTTP production site with "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

The app loads successfully in dev/localhost environment. But when published as Self-Contained or as a Framework Release deployments, it fails to load in production. The calling http:// request is returned with an https:// response and renders a page with a *This site can’t be reached* message. 
Can anyone shed some light on this?

I have tried with commenting out the following from Startup.cs file

```
//app.UseHsts();
//app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

In addition, I have disabled "Enable SSL"

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        //app.UseHsts();
    }

    //app.UseAuthentication();
    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue.
Initially this ASP.Net Core project was created with SSL Enabled. Despite removing / commenting the calls to the middleware HTTPS and HST components the app still failed when deployed to production. My solution was to create another app with SSL disabled and copy all my assets from the old project to the new. Rebuild Test and deployed to production. It worked without any issues.